# Issues with protocols bindings in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I tried to bind a native library in iOS (Objective-C) in Xamarin.iOS.

The header file is simple but I can't find a proper solution.

Here is the header file:

```
@protocol FooFinished

-(void)fooFinished:(NSString*)key;

@end

@protocol FooViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onClosed)();

@end

@interface Foo : NSObject {

}

+ (UIViewController<FooViewController>*)fooViewControllerWithFinish:(id<FooFinished>)f;

@end
```

And here is my bindings in ApiDefinition.cs :

```
namespace FooBindings
{
    interface IFooFinished { }

    // @protocol FooFinished <NSObject>
    [Protocol, Model]
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface FooFinished
    {
        // @required -(void)fooFinished:(NSString *)key;
        [Abstract]
        [Export("fooFinished:")]
        void FooFinishedWithKey(string key);
    }

    interface IFooViewController { }

    // @protocol FooViewController <NSObject>
    [Protocol, Model]
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface FooViewController
    {
        // @required @property (copy, nonatomic) void (^onClosed)();
        [Abstract]
        [Export("onClosed", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
        Action OnClosed { get; set; }
    }

    // @interface Foo : NSObject
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    interface Foo
    {
        // +(UIViewController<FooViewController> *)fooViewControllerWithFinish:(id<FooFinished>)f;
        [Static]
        [Export("fooViewControllerWithFinish:embedOptions:")]
        IFooViewController FooViewControllerWithFinish(IFooFinished f);
    }
}
```

And in my app, I have a MainViewController. Inside, I create my FooViewController like this:

```
public partial class MainViewController : UIViewController, IFooFinished
    {
        private IFooViewController Foo { get; set; }

        protected internal MainViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            startButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (Foo == null)
                {
                    Foo = Foo.FooViewControllerWithFinish(this);
                }

                this.PresentViewController(Foo, true, null);
            };
        }

        public void FooFinishedWithKey(string key)
        {
            this.DismissViewController(true, null);
        }
    }
```

My problem is: I can't use "this.PresentViewController(Foo, true, null);" because "Foo" is not a UIViewController. I tried to cast it but I have a exception that says "Invalid cast exception".

Thank you for helping me guys.

**EDIT**:
Got it working ! I made these changes in my ApiDefinition.cs:

```
// @interface Foo : NSObject
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface Foo
{
    // +(UIViewController<FooViewController> *)fooViewControllerWithFinish:(id<FooFinished>)f;
    [Static]
    [Export("fooViewControllerWithFinish:embedOptions:")]
    FooViewController FooViewControllerWithFinish(IFooFinished f);
}

[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[Protocol, Model]
interface IFooViewController
{
    // @required @property (copy, nonatomic) void (^onClosed)();
    [Abstract]
    [Export("onClosed", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    Action OnClosed { get; set; }
}

// @protocol FooViewController <NSObject>
[BaseType(typeof(UIViewController))]
[Model]
interface FooViewController : IFooViewController
{

}
```